# why if (element.innerHTML == "") is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, innerhtml

why is `if (element.innerHTML == "")` not working in firefox

but works fine in IE , any ideas please ?

Comment: Why not do a test output in Firefox and see what it contains?

Comment: @Pekka output already contains empty string !!

Comment: please supply HTML (the `element` that you are checking). in this scenario many things could go wrong - i.e. your `element` could be null.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your HTML, but I'd say probably because you have some empty white space in the element, and IE doesn't treat that as a text node, while FF does.

I believe it is actually a more strict standards compliance to treat any empty white space between tags as a text node, but IE doesn't comply.

You could do:

```
var htmlstring = element.innerHTML;

  // use the native .trim() if it exists
  //   otherwise use a regular expression  
htmlstring = (htmlstring.trim) ? htmlstring.trim() : htmlstring.replace(/^\s+/,'');

if(htmlstring == '') {...
```

Or just get rid of the whitespace in your HTML markup manually.

Comment: @Patrick dw : thnx for ur reply and useful info. , do u have any idea about how to make this condition works in FireFox ??

Comment: @mahmoud - For browsers that support `.trim()`, you could trim the whitespace before you test. Not all browsers support `.trim()` though. I'll update in a minute.

Comment: var str=element.innerHTML();
str = str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,"");
if (str == "") {
    alert('I'm so brilliant');
}

Comment: @Tomás - You could actually get rid of the last half of your regex. If the `innerHTML` only has white space, then it is redundant to test the beginning *and* the end of the string.

Comment: @all : thnx for your great support :)

Answer (score 8):

An alternative method to check for the empty string is to check the length:

```
element.innerHTML.length == 0
```

But, you'd still have to `trim()` if you had a whitespace string you wanted to match.

Answer (score 7):

You could check if `element.innerHTML.trim() == ""` for the best results. However, then you have to extend the string prototype with a `trim()` method:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, ''); };
}

if (element.innerHTML.trim() == "") {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: This would overwrite any native implementation in browsers that support `.trim()`. You should really test for it first.

Comment: Yep, I think that would cover it. :o)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it seemed like setting my `innerHTML` was not working in `Firefox` nor `Chrome` but it did work in `IE` because of my error. It turned out that I was never getting the element using `getElementById` in the first place. `IE` seems to do just fine with elements which are defined with `name=` with `getElementById` but `Firefox` and `Chrome` was more stringent and accepts only `id=` elements. (More correctly in my view)
I hope this saves somebody some frustration. 
 Why does IE do these sorts of things and confuse people...